# Zoomed image didn't close in Magento 2.2.3 and 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, php, knockoutjs, requirejs, magento2.2.3

I have just installed Magento 2.2.3 in my system. I have also added few categories and that of products. I can see a bigger image when I have clicked on it and it has been closed when I clicked on "X" (close) button. But when I checked in responsive design I am not able to close that image by clicking on close button. I have found the same issue in Magento 2.2.4 also.

Can someone please help me where the actual issue is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed on this,
You can take code from there and check.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/dd9d57f170282900b32513ed4c7142f81cd413e1

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help and helpful hint. But the thing is when I have checked that file, the code was already there and when I have checked the same in another version (i.e. Magento 2.1.1.1) the code was not there. When I have commented code given in your link, it worked for me.

One more thing suggestible is that, Magento will need to remove that line from their versions like 2.2.3 and higher, so that will work in future also.

Once again thanks for your link and hint.

Comment: welcome, Magento does the marge in next versions after the commits, it has merged in ver 2.2.5.
Anyways, if you find the answer helpful accept it so that it can be useful to others.